# Bash script issue with curl command containing parameters

Tags: bash, curl

I am running bash script with curl command in it.
I read the username, password and url from a properties file. 
But when the command gets executed, the response  gives me an error with saying you are not authorized to access this page.
I print out the whole curl command and it is correct.

Here is the part of the code:

this gives me response saying not authorized:

```
curl -u $USERNAMEVAL:$PWDVAL $URLVAL
```

this works perfectly even from inside bash program:

```
curl -u test\\test:test www.blah.com
```

What could be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you may want to add the fact you are using NTLM. ;auth=NTLM

Comment: This could be related to the quoting of the backslashes. Could you show us how you assign values to `$USERNAMEVAL`?

Comment: I add the value to the $USERNAMEVAL by reading from a properties file in the follwing way:                                                     for line in `cat webservice.properties| grep -v ^#`
do
  name=$(echo $line | awk -F\= '{print $1}')
  value=$(echo $line | awk -F\= '{print $2}')
  #echo $name=$value
  if [ "$name" == "$URL" ]; then
        URLVAL=$value
  fi
  if [ "$name" == "$USERNAME" ]; then
        USERNAMEVAL=$value
  fi
  if [ "$name" == "$PWD" ]; then
        PWDVAL=$value
  fi
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a situation where a command in a Bash shell script fails yet the same command with what I think are the same parameters works when I manually run it, I suspect an issue with either the parameter values or the parameter quoting.

As an initial step in isolating the problem, I'd suggest that immediately before the line

```
curl -u $USERNAMEVAL:$PWDVAL $URLVAL
```

you add something such as

```
echo "curl -u $USERNAMEVAL:$PWDVAL $URLVAL"
```

Or even (to be very clear):

```
echo "\$USERNAMEVAL(${#USERNAMEVAL}): \"$USERNAMEVAL\""
echo "\$PWDVAL(${#PWDVAL}): \"$PWDVAL\""
echo "\$URLVAL(${#URLVAL}): \"$URLVAL\""
echo "curl -u $USERNAMEVAL:$PWDVAL $URLVAL"
```

This prints the name, length, and value of each of the variables being used to construct the `curl` command.

E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAMEVAL='test\\test'
PWDVAL='test'
URLVAL='www.blah.com'

echo "\$USERNAMEVAL(${#USERNAMEVAL}): \"$USERNAMEVAL\""
echo "\$PWDVAL(${#PWDVAL}): \"$PWDVAL\""
echo "\$URLVAL(${#URLVAL}): \"$URLVAL\""
echo "curl -u $USERNAMEVAL:$PWDVAL $URLVAL"
```

This prints:

```
$USERNAMEVAL(10): "test\\test"
$PWDVAL(4): "test"
$URLVAL(12): "www.blah.com"
curl -u test\\test:test www.blah.com
```